# Valid placement of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations on properties and Encapsulated fields

Tags: c#, data-annotations, system.componentmodel

I'm using various syntaxes of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` within my Model. Wondering if there's any implications on `DataAnnotations` placement using this short hand syntax and also the placement seen further below where `DataAnnotations` are on the Attributes and not Accessor & Modifier methods.

**My Model with what I believe is best practice placement for `DataAnnotations` and this works as expected when I add OData support to my Database Context class not posted here**

```
public class WebOrder
{
    private Guid _id;
    private float _total;
    private string _name;         

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public float Total
    {
        get { return _total; }
        set { _total = value; }
    }        

    [Required]
    public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
}
```

**Would this placement of `DataAnnotations` also be considered valid**

```
public class WebOrder
{
    [Key]
    private Guid _id;
    [Required]     
    private float _total;
    [Required]    
    private string _name;         

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public float Total
    {
        get { return _total; }
        set { _total = value; }
    }        

    public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
}
```

Comment: When you tried it, did it work as expected?

Comment: the first code snippet does, the second one I have not tested